# Creating a Google Document via the REST API v1 & PHP

Tags: php, google-docs-api

I've been exploring the various Document APIs and have settled on [Google Docs API v1](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/php) to try to accomplish what I want.

What I want to accomplish:

- Create A Doc
- Dump some text into it
- Place the doc into a G Suite Drive Folder

What I've got

- All the respective relevant APIs enabled + Service Account Credentials (have used this with other Google Services just fine)
- All of the Google API PHP stuff installed via composer
- What I think is a method to correctly authenticate into the "Documents" REST API (please see below)

  ```
  public function initializeDocs() {

      // Create and configure a new client object.
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName($appName);
      $client->setAuthConfig("$KEY_FILE_LOCATION");
      $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']);

      $document = new Google_Service_Docs_Document($client);
      $document->setTitle($title);

      return $document; // Just seeing what get outputs

      /*
      ...Getting Stuck here below is the code from Google's "Creating and managing documents" documentation

      $document = new Google_Service_Docs_Document(array(
          'title' => $title
      ));

      $document = $service->documents->create($document);
      printf("Created document with title: %s\n", $document->title);

      After this....(can/will address in separate post, if possible)
      1) Add content
      2) Set document creator?
      3) "Upload" / move to Drive folder location

      */

  }
  ```

My issues:

- I'm having a hard time finding/undersanding 'create' methods; Google's [Creating and managing documents](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents#php) references the ['Documents Collection'](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents)
- At least in the PHP library, I'm not seeing where I would find that (I searched the `~/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Docs` directory and didn't see any 'create' method);

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. In your question, you say `All the respective relevant APIs enabled + Service Account Credentials (have used this with other Google Services just fine)`. But in your script, `setAuthConfig("$KEY_FILE_LOCATION")` is used. I thought that `setAuthConfig` is used for OAuth2. How about this? 2. About your flow of `1. Create A Doc`, `2. Dump some text into it` and `3. Place the doc into a G Suite Drive Folder`, I think that in this case, this flow can be achieved using only Drive API. How about this?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what issue you are facing? I don't understand what's stopping you. You can create the document with [documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents#creating_a_blank_document), insert content with [documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text#inserting_text) and move it to a certain Drive location with [files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#moving_files_between_folders).